# Comprovante de publicação de App

Tags: android, ios, mobile, app

Preciso de documentos que comprovem a publicação de um App feito por mim na Apple Store e Google Play, onde posso cobsegui-los?

Comment: que tipo de documentação? nunca vi nada desse tipo, mas o que tu pode fazer é tirar prints da publicação do app pela tua conta nos painéis

Comment: Preciso comprovar que o aplicativo é meu.